# PayPal Soap API Balance for certain Date

Tags: soap, paypal

I'm using the PayPal Soap-Api.

With the "GetBalance"-Api Operation it's possible to get the current Balance.

But for Accounting reasons, I need to fetch the Balance for every Day in a certain period. e.g.

- 22.01.2016, Balance: 500,00 €
- 21.01.2016, Balance: 425,00 €
- 20.01.2016, Balance: 964,60 €
- ...
- 01.01.2015, Balance: 0,00 €

I found no Api-Operation that would match my needs.

So I tried to use the "TransactionSearch"-Api Operation to get the Transactions for this period and calculate the Balance.

Since there is no documentation wether a Transaction is balance-affecting or not, my calculation always failed.

It is possible to set certain filters for the "TransactionSearch"-Api Operation like "BalanceAffecting". But also with this filter set, I get the wrong Transactions to calculate the Balance for every day.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there seems to be no way to get the Balance for each day...sorry